# Extract rows of last column

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `A` with dimension 4x4x40.
I want to extract first three rows of last column and put it into a new matrix `B` such that my new matrix `B` would have dimension 40x3.

```
for idx=1:40
    B(:,idx)=A(1:3,4,idx)
end
```

However, I am getting `B` as 3x1x40.

Comment: This code works fine in R2015a... apart from missing initialisation obviously. I thought MATLAB only stripped trailing singleton dimensions, I guess they improved on that lately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `squeeze` command:

```
B = squeeze(A(1:3, 4, :))
```

Comment: you might want to add a `.'` there too :)